# Recursive definitions of $n<m$, $n\mid m$, and $n \bmod m$

Tags: arithmetic, recursion

Without referring to the apparatus of [(primitive) recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) one can introduce addition into the language of successor arithmetic by two additional axioms which naturally reflect the essence of recursion:

- $(\forall n)\ n + 0 = n$
- $(\forall n, m)\ n+ m' = (n+m)'$

When we already have addition, it is easy to re-define $<$ explicitely:

- $n < m :\equiv (\exists x \neq 0)\ n + x = m$

> I wonder if the following is a sound recursive definition of $<$ only using the successor function:
>
> - $(\forall n)\ n < n'$
> - $(\forall n,m)\ n < m \rightarrow n < m'$

Other than the usual recursive definitions this one does not involve $0$, but it seems to work anyway. A proof that $0 < 2$ (with $2=1'=0''$) goes like this: Assume that $\neg(0 < 2)$. Since $\neg(n < m') \rightarrow \neg(n < m)$ it follows $\neg(0 < 0')$. Contradiction.

Note that the successor function could in turn be re-defined explicitely by the given relation $<$:

- $m = n' :\equiv n < m \wedge \neg(\exists x)\ n < x < m$

I'd like to drive this further: Before defining multiplication (recursively) I'd like to define the intermediate relation $n \mid m$ ("$n$ divides $m$") and function $n\bmod m$ ("the remainder of $n$ divided by $m$") in a similar recursive fashion as $n < m$, especially without using multiplication (only addition).

The $n\mid m$ case seems easy:

> - $(\forall n \neq 0)\ n \mid n$
> - $(\forall n \neq 0,m \geq n)\ n \mid m \rightarrow n \mid (m + n)$

But I get stuck trying to define  $n\bmod m$ in a similar fashion. Other than $n<m$ and $n\mid m$ it is a function, not a relation, but it should be possible, shouldn't it?

Any hint is welcome.

**[Addendum]**

> Supposed that $n \bmod m$ can be defined by additional axioms in a
>   recursive fashion, can addition be re-defined explicitely by $\bmod$ -
>   just like the successor function can be re-defined explicitely by $<$?

Comment: Thanks, Michael, for the TeX-nical improvements!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier than I thought it is?

> - $(\forall m)\ 0\bmod m = 0$
> - $(\forall n,m)\ (n\bmod m)' = m \rightarrow n'\bmod m = 0$
> - $(\forall n,m)\ (n\bmod m)' \neq m \rightarrow n'\bmod m = (n\bmod m)'$